What is a trillesti?
While cycling in Norway I passed along signs with bicycling information that were marking some routes as "trillesti" or "trillestier".  This word is not in my paper dictionary, nor on wiktionary, nor on ordbøkene.no.
A DDG web search appears to give exclusively results related to cycling.
Example of an information panel with trillestier in the legend in the bottom left:

What is a trillesti?

It is a path that you can "trille", wheel your bike through (so holding it and dragging it on the path), but that probably is not good enough to actually bike on, perhaps because it's very bulky, full of rocks, etc. I grew up in Norway and know this from word of mouth and from visiting the paths (they occur throughout the country).

Ah, at least trille is listed in dictionaries :)

Google translated it to Dutch as Karrepad or karrespoor, in English that would be cart track, indicating poor surface but recognizable path.

@Willeke Somehow I didn't think of trying machine translation.  But a trail so poor one has to push one's bike (like the German Schiebestrecke) sounds considerably worse than a cart track.

A karrespoor is the worst surface track we used to have in the Netherlands till mountainbiking became a thing, so that might be the explanation.

+1 For whatever it is worth, LLMs do a surprisingly good job at translating more obscure and/or contextual words. For example ChatGPT ends up translating trillesti as "push bike path" and explains "In Norwegian, the term "trillesti" refers to a type of path specifically designed for walking or pushing a bicycle, rather than riding it. These paths are often found in areas where the terrain is too steep, narrow, or otherwise unsuitable for cycling, requiring cyclists to dismount and push their bikes."

Even as a Norwegian, avid cyclist, I have never heard trillesti before and would not have intuitively understood it. I know the expression trilletur, which in the area I used to live was used for routes on unpaved paths and roads, where the surface is good enough to push a stroller. I would have assumed that a trillesti is a path good enough to walk with a stroller, not a path too poor to cycle, so that you have to walk your bike.

@Tor-Einar That’s interesting – as a non-Norwegian who bikes for reasons of practicality and necessity rather than out of any actual love for it, I immediately understood it. Granted, I would perhaps have understood it as a path where you’re not allowed to cycle and have to push the bike instead, for whatever reason (narrow path, danger of loose gravel, too steep, etc.), but I definitely associated it with pushing a bike.

@JanusBahsJacquet The expression seems to be used with quite different meanings in different contexts. I have found several official documents where "trillesti" has been used to describe a path or road good enough to allow wheelchair access as well.

Looking at Google satellite view, Poli's interpretation looks like the correct one, and not @Tor-EinarJarnbjo's. Where the sykkelruter is red, there are paved roads, and where the trillesti is dark blue, there are no paved roads, only dirt path.

@shoover In this case, Poli is correct. I've never doubted that. I just wanted to point out that it is an unusual expression, which is also used with other meanings.

@gerrit sti and its plural stier are also in dictionaries.

@Henry Yes, but I know sti and thus don't need a dictionary in this case :)
